# How to find difference in Joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to use the `Interval` class of Joda Time but I am unable to use its constructor. It does not take the format.

I am trying to extract two `DateTime` from mysql DB in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and it is retrieved in `String` format. I am trying to convert it into date format but the interval class is unable to take date formats. Please help what should I use???

```
    String text = "2011-10-02 18:48:05";
    String text2 = "2011-10-02 18:50:05";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
            Date olddate=sdf.parse(text);
            Date newdate=sdf.parse(text2);
            System.out.println(olddate);
            System.out.println(newdate);
//            Interval interval = new Interval(olddate, newdate);



        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error at Timestamp subtract Format function Dategenerator" + ex.getMessage());

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `java.util.Date`, but Joda Time's `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

For parsing use Joda Time's `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`.

That should work:

```
    String text = "2011-10-02 18:48:05";
    String text2 = "2011-10-02 18:50:05";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime oldDate = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
    DateTime newDate = formatter.parseDateTime(text2);
    System.out.println(oldDate);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    Interval interval = new Interval(oldDate, newDate);
    System.out.println(interval);
```

Comment: TY very much, I was using the old date format with joda time. Thats exactly what I needed. I was able to get the minutes easily from it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the minutes difference using this code in joda time:

```
String text = "2011-10-02 15:48:05";
        String text2 = "2011-10-02 18:52:10";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime oldDate = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
        DateTime newDate = formatter.parseDateTime(text2);
        System.out.println(oldDate);
        System.out.println(newDate);
        Interval interval = new Interval(oldDate, newDate);        
        System.out.println(interval.toDuration().toPeriod().getHours()*60+  interval.toDuration().toPeriod().getMinutes());
```

Comment: The length in minutes you get by `interval.toDuration().getStandardMinutes()`.

Comment: true but it returns double not int